# Help with $f \circ g$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing this problem and so far I've learned $f\circ g$ where I've been given $f(x)$ and $g(x).$ In this case, I'm not. How would I solve this?

> Express the function in the form $f\circ g$ if $g(t)=\cot(t):$
>
> $u(t)=\sqrt{\cot(t)}$
>
> $f(t)=?$

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this not a valid question?

Comment: The question is problematic, $u$ is not defined... assuming that $u=f\circ g$ you can take $f(t)=\sqrt{t}$. (I did not downvote)

Comment: @Hyp11: It's not that your question is invalid. It's that on M.SE, we expect questions to have more context. In your case, you should tell us what you've tried, and if there is more context, you should give us that. It helps us help you.

Comment: What is $u(t)$ supposed to be?  All we know is that $f\circ g = f(\cot(t))$.

Comment: Sorry guys, this question had me stoked so I couldn't really attempt anything. I gave my answer and reasoning below. The question was presented as is without any context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meh, too much negativity. Apologies I couldn't give more context because this question had me stuck and I've never done it before but I figured it out. The question does not tell you this but it is assumed that $f\circ g = u(t)$. They give you the value of $g(t)$ being $g(t)=\cot(t)$. Using this info and understanding that $f(g(t)) = f(cot(t)) = u(t)$ the rest is easy. It's radical $t$.